# MySQL | fetch_array get second of array

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the first 10 results of an array, but with the current code, it lets my one get the first one.

```
$query = "SELECT name FROM `table` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($sql, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);

echo $row['0']; //I can do this.
echo $row['2']; // I can't do this. (It's echoing nothing).
```

How can I get number 1, 2,3 etc... from an array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    echo $row[0] . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function [mysqli_fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) only fetches one row of data, so the array you're accessing only contains the columns of that row. As you're selecting only one column, it contains only one value.

You'd have to make multiple calls to fetch_array() to access the following rows, or just use [mysqli_fetch_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) instead, which returns an array of rows.

For example:

```
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
echo $rows[0][0];
echo $rows[1][0];
```

Notice that you have an index for the row, and another for the column.